# Building PECL extension on windows

Tags: php, dll, msbuild, pecl

I want to build an old version of [APC](http://in.php.net/manual/en/apc.installation.php) on windows. They say (check the link)

> A DLL for this PECL extension is currently unavailable. See also the building on Windows section.

but the guides referred are not available. Can you recommend a How-to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tried this last night and I also needed to download the PHP sourcefiles, Zlib source, and OpenSSL source, and build Zlib and openSSl static libraries to get all the references. But then once I had all the references squared aware the darn thing still errored on the build because something was redefined.

And I know what you mean, this process is not documented at all. Personally I don't think there is a windwows DLL to download because they couldn't get it to build either.